# How to display yearly values on xAxis in Highcharts

Tags: csv, highcharts, timestamp

I guess this is somewhat of a stupid question. But I am struggling since quite a while with this, not finding what the right way of data formatting is for my data.

I have yearly data like this, which I want to have displayed as such - 2001, 2002, 2003, ...:

```
time,lat,lon,Npp_1km
Date.UTC(2001/1/1),15,-90,1.266112766
Date.UTC(2002/1/1),15,-90,1.166646809
Date.UTC(2003/1/1),15,-90,1.020591489
Date.UTC(2004/1/1),15,-90,1.016010638
Date.UTC(2005/12/31),15,-90,1.08053617
Date.UTC(2006/12/31),15,-90,1.181195745
```

and my Highcharts code which looks like this:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: "#666666"
    },
    x: 0
  },
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
  tickWidth: 0,
  type: 'datetime'
},
```

But the xAxis doesn't display the years but instead some "00:00:00.001". 
I have tried many different formats for the timestamp - "2001-1-1", "2001/1/1", "1/1/2001", "1-1-2001", "Date.UTC(2001/1/1)". I have changed the "dateTimeLabelFormats" as well. But all in vain. It doesn't spit out "2001 - 2002 - 2003 - 2004".

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/pcpq6mtr/3/).

What is the right way to achieve this? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had problems with parsing your data. All of your x values was not correct - that is the reason of your issue. You need to parse it a little bit different if you want to get the correct data for your chart:

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
var temp = []
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');
// For each line, split the record into seperate attributes
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
  var items = line.split(',');
  if (lineNo !== 0) {
    items[0] = items[0].substring(items[0].indexOf('(') + 1, items[0].indexOf(')'));
    var x = new Date(items[0]),
      y = parseFloat(items[3]);
    if (!isNaN(y)) {
      x = x.getTime();
      options.series[0].data.push([x, y]);
    }
  }
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pcpq6mtr/4/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be put categories in xAxis if the time is fixed.

```
xAxis {
    categories:[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006]
}
```

If the time is not fixed. categories need to be calculated dynamically.